# PHP Pear Mail HTML Version

Tags: php, html, email, pear

I'm able to send emails with text only, but none of the scripts are working to send HTML. I have authentication off, and google apps is authenticating based on the server IP

```
$message = 'Blah blah blah';


require_once "Mail.php";
$from = "mycompany <service@mycompany.com>";
$to = $fName.$lName." <".$email.">";
$subject = "Hello from mycompany!";
$body =

'Dear '.$fName.',

Thank you for your interest in mycompany. We have received your inquiry and will contact you within 24 hours.

Thanks,

Timothy Elliott - Owner/CEO mycompany';

                      $host = "tls://smtp-relay.gmail.com";
                      $port = "465";
                      $username = "";
                      $password = "";
                      $headers = array (
                        'From' => $from,
                        'To' => $to,
                        'Subject' => $subject);
                      $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
                        array ('host' => $host,
                          'port' => $port,
                          'auth' => false,
                          'username' => $username,
                          'password' => $password));
                      $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
 echo("There was an error, please try again.");
}
```

This code works just fine, but I'm not able to send it as an HTML message.

Comment: There is no easy way to send HTML messages with Pear Mail. You might consider using something like http://swiftmailer.org/ or http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mail.introduction.html

Comment: Ohh good to know! I am on a shared server though and can't install any scripts :( Dang fatcow!! :(

Comment: No installation needed. You can upload Zend Mail and Swift Mailer in parallel to your own PHP scripts. They do not require any special setup on the server side.

Comment: What about PHPMailer?

Comment: Yes. PHP mailer is just two class files you need to include. It supports html  and inline images.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea how to store incoming messages? I would much rather have all the emails go in and out of my site instead of having to pay for google apps for every employee

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to do with with PEAR Mail - you just need to use PEAR Mail_Mime for encoding the HTML portion of your outgoing emails.

[Here's an example of how.](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php)

Expanding your code for this, it should look something like:

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/mime.php";

$from = "mycompany <service@mycompany.com>";
$to = $fName.$lName." <".$email.">";
$subject = "Hello from mycompany!";
$html = <<< HTML
<b>Dear $fName</b>,
<p>
Thank you for your interest in mycompany. We have received your inquiry and will contact you within 24 hours.
</p>
Thanks,<br/>

<i>Timothy Elliott - Owner/CEO mycompany</i>
HTML;

$host = "tls://smtp-relay.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$headers = [
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
];

$crlf = "\n";
$mime = new Mail_mime(['eol' => $crlf]);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);


$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
    [
    'host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => false,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password
    ]
);
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("There was an error, please try again.");
}
```

Comment: Something in the html section is giving me PHP errors...I get an unexpected end at the end of my script

Comment: If you're using heredoc notation for setting up HTML you need to ensure the end marker, "HTML;" is at the very start of the line with no spaces/tabs before it.